# Data Structure for category tree

Tags: data-structures, tree, combinations

I'm writing a program that compiles song prices. Each song has two properties that we care about: The territory that it's being sold in (String value e.g. "Europe") and the method for which it is sold (String e.g. "Stream").

I am reading from a data base with thousands of elements of the same song and have to sum up the money that a singular song generates in each territory with each format, so for example:

"Song Title1", "Europe", "Stream" : $2.20

"Song Title1", "N. America", "Stream" : $4.25

"Song Title1", "Europe", "live performance" : $1.20
etc.

I know the answer is probably obvious, but I feel like I'm not taking a smart approach. essentially I envisioned multiple dictionaries. From a mathematical, number of elements in the tree would be the combination of total properties.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I don't understand your question because ... well ... what *is* the question here? A list of territories, each with a list of streaming formats and their sum, is that what you mean by "multiple dictionaries"?

Comment: Essentially I wanted to implement something like a hashtable/map which would have 3 keys and 1 value.

Answer (score 1):

If I got your question right, then you could create some kind of `Key` from first three columns, so `Title`, `Region`, `Perform Method` and the value for that key would be you `price`.

Than put your `Key-Value` pair in some implementation of `Hashtable` datastructure and update a price on adding. I know, that it might be not the perfect solution, but quite obvious one from a first look.

Of course you can make a prefix tree if you want.